# Redux form props & typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux-form, definitelytyped

Was looking for years, didn't find anything worthy tho.

When I was working with flow, I could simply:

```
import { type FieldProps, FormProps } from 'redux-form';
```

Is there a similar (and that easy) way to properly set props to redux form in typescript?

Docs aren't saying anything about typescript, there's only a page for Flow typings.

However, I found that I can import something like `propTypes` from redux-form:

```
import { reduxForm, propTypes } from 'redux-form'
```

However - `redux-form` has nothing like `propTypes` exported, so docs are kinda deprecated.

Link: https://redux-form.com/7.2.1/docs/api/props.md/

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

```
tl;dr class RegistrationForm extends React.PureComponent<any> {
                                      what to drop here ^^^^^
```

Comment: Have you tried `import {FieldProps, FormProps} from 'redux-form';`? In TypeScript you do not indicate that you are importing a _type_ with a special keyword, you just import the type.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes, I tried. `redux-form` has nothing like `FieldProps` or `FormProps` exported :(

Comment: You need to install the `@types/redux-form` package with your package manager.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Included `<FormProps<any, any>>` but it still doesn't work properly. It says that e.g. `handleSubmit` function was not found in props, even, if it is there.

Comment: See `InjectedFormProps<FormData = {}, P = {}>` in `reduxForm.d.ts`. Note that default values of the type parameters make specifying them optional.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Should I import these `InjectedFormProps` from somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. You haven't shown how you would have done it in Flow but there should be analogous types declared in the `@types` package.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to install the `@types/redux-form` package with your package manager. The `@types/redux-form` package includes types definitions for `redux-form` package.

Then you can import type definitions from `redux-form`, for example `InjectedFormProps`.

Your form that will be wrapped with `reduxForm()` should has props that extends `InjectedFormProps<FormData = {}, P = {}>`.

`reduxForm()` type is generic `reduxForm<FormData = {}, P = {}>(...`

See the example:

```ts
import * as React from 'react';
import { reduxForm, InjectedFormProps, Field } from 'redux-form';

import { IUser } from './index';

interface IProps {
  message: string;
}

class UserForm extends React.Component<InjectedFormProps<IUser, IProps> & IProps> {
  render() {
    const { pristine, submitting, reset, handleSubmit, message } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>{message}</div>
        <div>
          <label>First Name </label>
          <Field
            name="firstName"
            component="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="First Name"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Last Name </label>
          <Field
            name="lastName"
            component="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Last Name"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}>
            Submit
          </button>
          <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>
            Clear Values
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm<IUser, IProps>({
  form: 'userForm',
})(UserForm);
```

[image: Edit Redux Form + Typescript example]

The source code of `@types/redux-form` package is located [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/redux-form). You can see the types there and more complicated examples in the [redux-form-tests.tsx](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/redux-form/redux-form-tests.tsx) file that is used for types checking.

Comment: I believe it should be `React.Component<InjectedFormProps<IUser, IProps> & IProps>`, at least as of today.

Comment: My IDE gives `InjectedFormProps not found in 'redux-form'eslint(import/named)
` when importing, but it still compiles and run, any idea?

Comment: @zerkms, thanks, fix to `React.Component<InjectedFormProps<IUser, IProps> & IProps>`